# ("Parameter "" for route "" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) using pagerfanta

Tags: symfony, pagerfanta

I'm attempting to get PagerFanta working to page my data. I can view the first page and the generated code in the `pagerfanta` portion generates all the correct links, however when I click on any of those corresponding links I get the exception in the title. It seems like the `pagerfanta` twig function is not giving the correct parameter when generating the routes.

Controller action:

```
/**
     * @Route("/people/{page}", name="view_people")
     * @Template("AppBundle:Default:people.html.twig")
     */
    public function viewPeopleAction($page)
    {
        $people = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Person')
            ->findAll();
        $adapter = new ArrayAdapter($people);
        $pager = new Pagerfanta($adapter);
        $pager->setMaxPerPage(45);

        try {
            $pager->setCurrentPage($page);
        } catch(NotValidCurrentPageException $e) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        return array('pager' => $pager);
    }
```

Twig page:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <table>
  {% for object in pager.currentPageResults %}
    <tr>
      <td><a href="{{ path('view_person', {'personid': object.id}) }}">{{ object.name }}</a></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>

{% if pager.haveToPaginate %}
  {{ pagerfanta(pager, "twitter_bootstrap_translated", {"routeName": "view_people", "pageParameter": "[page]"} ) }}
{% endif %}
{% endblock body %}
{% block javascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Full error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "page" for route "view_people" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in AppBundle:Default:people.html.twig at line 15.

500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
1 linked Exception:
InvalidParameterException »

[2/2] Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Parameter "page" for route "view_people" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in AppBundle:Default:people.html.twig at line 15.   +

[1/2] InvalidParameterException: Parameter "page" for route "view_people" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.
```

What is wrong with my code that is causing this error?
Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a default value for the `page` parameter as this one will be omitted when the page is one:

```
/**
 * @Route("/people/{page}", name="view_people", defaults={"page"=1})
 * @Template("AppBundle:Default:people.html.twig")
 */
public function viewPeopleAction($page)
{
    // ...
}
```