# Pass several parameters correctly to your controller

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine, twig

I have already inquired [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551148/parameter-for-route-must-match-given-to-generate-a-correspo) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500794/parameter-for-route-must-match-given-using-pagerfanta) but nothing more or less corresponds to my problem.

I have a page with information about a movie, which I access with an id parameter:

```
<a href="{{path('film', {'id': film.id{){{" class="btn btn-primary"> See comments </a>
```

The film table having a relation with the table how, I display all the comments specific to the movie thanks to an **ArrayCollection** :

```php
 $filmRepo = $repo->find($id);

 $comments = $filmRepo->getComments();
```

I created a CommentController in which I wrote this method whose goal would be to recover the id of the movie **AND** the id of the comment in order to be able to make **CRUD operations** on it:

```php
/**
  * @Route("{id}/{comment}/create", name="createComment")
  * @Route("{id}/{comment}/modif", name="modifComment", defaults={"comment"=1}, methods="GET|POST")
  */
    public function modification(Comment $comment = null, Film $film, Request $req, EntityManagerInterface $em) 
    {
        if(!$comment) {
            $comment = new Comment();
        }

        $user = $this->getUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
        $form->handleRequest($req);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $comment->setAuthor($user);
            $comment->setFilm($film);
            $em->persist($comment);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'L\'action a bien été effectuée');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        return $this->render('comment/modif.html.twig', [
            "comment" => $comment,
            "form" => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

But no matter which comment I select, it takes the default comment, that is to say the one with id 1. So something is wrong with my request. However I pass the two parameters in the twig template:

```
<a href="{{path('modifComment', {'id' : film.id }, {'comment' : comment.id})}}">Modif</a>
```

Comment: There is a typo here: `{{path('film', {'id': film.id{`

Comment: What's the actual html in your browser with this piece of code? `<a href="{{path('modifComment', {'id' : film.id }, {'comment' : comment.id})}}">Modif</a>` I'm expecting something like `<a href="/modifyComment/id/123/comment/456>Modif</a>`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte <a href="../1/1/modif">Modifier</a> I have this in my browser

Comment: You have `@Route("{id}/{comment}/modif"` so film id = 1 and comment id = 1. Is that what you expect? If not, update your question with the code where you mount the link and should have different `comment.id` than 1

Comment: @FelippeDuarte It's what a expect for the comment 1 of the film 1. But when i choose a comment 4 of the film 1, for example, that brings me back to comment 1 (which is logical because I put it by default in my modification method

Comment: Ok so how is the link for comment 4? It's 1/1/modif or 1/4/modif? The value of `{'comment' : comment.id}` comes from where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from a syntax error in the twig template. Instead of :

```
<a href="{{path('modifComment', {'id' : film.id }, {'comment' : comment.id})}}">Modif</a>
```

Rather do :

```
<a href="{{path('modifComment', {'id' : film.id, 'comment' : comment.id})}}">Modif</a>
```